# Kendo UI grid return json string with html tags

Tags: php, grid, kendo-ui

my script transaction.php return following json format

```
    $TransactionSumary[0] = array(
        'ExchangeRate' => 'USD = 7,800 | THB 250',
        'Total' => '250,000 LAK',
        'VAT'   => '25,000 LAK',
        'GrandTotalUSD' => '15.00',
        'GrandTotalTHB' => '1,000',
        'GrandTotalLAK' => '<span class="k-block k-success-colored">250,000</span>',
);

echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($TransactionSumary).")";
```

Please look at `GrandTotalLAK`, it contain some HTML tags,

the problem is the `GrandTotalLAK` is not display as HTML format property it shown as flat character `<span class="k-block k-success-colored">250,000</span>` in Kendo UI Grid,

If I use `base64_encode("<span class="k-block k-success-colored">250,000</span>")`, and how to decode it in Kendo UI Grid column properties?

here is the Kendo UI Grid cloumn property

```
{ field:"GrandTotalLAK", title: "Grand Total (LAK)", width: "20%" },
```

Thank you very much!

OK after some Google I found solution

`<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name", encoded: false }
  ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "<strong>Jane Doe</strong>" } ]
});
</script>`

Answer (score 4):

rather then passing the html on GrandTotalLak, just pass the value and set the template for that particular columns to how you want to display.

for eg:-

```
 <script id="column_template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span class="k-block k-success-colored"> #= GrandTotalLAK #</span>
 </script>
```

then inside the columns of your specific field define the above template id like

```
template: kendo.template(jQuery("#column_template").html()),
```

I hope it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for another solution my friend!

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Kendo Grid not to encode your data using the [columns.encoded](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.encoded) property - i.e. change your column definition to:

```
columns: [{
  field:"GrandTotalLAK",
  title: "Grand Total (LAK)",
  width: "20%",
  encoded: false
}]
```

**Update:** I see you've added that solution to your question - I'll leave my answer here in case anyone else reads too quickly as well!